# radar chart / spider chart xsl-fo svg?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, radar-chart, spider-chart, svggraph

I have to generate a pdf document written in xsl-fo. I have 8 categories where I pull the percentage into the xsl-fo document, and I need to visualize it on a radar chart.
Is it possible to create a spider chart in xsl-fo? 
Maybe in svg and inserting it as an instream-foreign-object?
[This is how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciErG.png)

Comment: What is your concrete problem? To generate such a svg-file? How to insert it as a foreign object? How to generate the dynamic shape from the percentage values?

Comment: I would like to generate the spider chart, based on percentage values, in a XSL-FO document. It could embedded into a svg code or a foreign object, it doesn't matter as long as the spider chart changes based on the percentage changes. My main issue that I haven't seen any spider chart related code in XSL-FO coding, only in JS, and I don't know how to convert one into another, if at all possible, since I'm not a developer.